# Python VTK: Coordinates directly to PolyData

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

I want to convert all coordinate combinations for x,y and z in specific range with for now step 1 directly to vtk.polyData or vtk.points. My first approach was to use itertools.product, but I thought this would have a very bad runtime. So i came to another approach with vtk, which i need anyway for the next part sof my program.

**First appraoch with itertools.product**

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import vtk

x1=[10,11,12....310]
y1=[10,11,12....310]
z1=[0,1,2....65]

points1 = vtk.vtkPoints()                      
for coords in itertools.product(x1,y1,z1):
   points1.InsertNextPoint(coords)
boxPolyData1 = vtk.vtkPolyData()
boxPolyData1.SetPoints(points1)
```

**My approach with vtk so far:**

```
import numpy as np
from vtk.util import numpy_support

coords = np.mgrid[10:310, 10:310, 0:65]
vtk_data_array = numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(num_array=coords.ravel(),deep=True,array_type=vtk.VTK_FLOAT)

points = vtk.vtkPoints()
points.SetData(vtk_data_array)
```

But his just crashes my python. Does anyone has an idea?

best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack those `coords` in columns with [`np.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) or [`np.c_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) and then feed those as input to `num_array`, like so -

```
x,y,z = np.mgrid[10:310, 10:310, 0:65]
out_data = np.column_stack((x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel()))

vtk_data_array = numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(num_array=out_data,\
                              deep=True,array_type=vtk.VTK_FLOAT)
```

Alternatively, to get `out_data` directly -

```
out_data = np.mgrid[10:310, 10:310, 0:65].reshape(3,-1).T
```

Another approach using `initialization` to replace the `3D` array created by `np.mgrid` would be like so -

```
def create_mgrid_array(d00,d01,d10,d11,d20,d21,dtype=int):
    df0 = d01-d00
    df1 = d11-d10
    df2 = d21-d20
    a = np.zeros((df0,df1,df2,3),dtype=dtype)
    X,Y,Z = np.ogrid[d00:d01,d10:d11,d20:d21]
    a[:,:,:,2] = Z
    a[:,:,:,1] = Y
    a[:,:,:,0] = X
    a.shape = (-1,3)
    return a
```

Sample run to showcase usage of `create_mgrid_array` -

```
In [151]: create_mgrid_array(3,6,10,14,20,22,dtype=int)
Out[151]: 
array([[ 3, 10, 20],
       [ 3, 10, 21],
       [ 3, 11, 20],
       [ 3, 11, 21],
       [ 3, 12, 20],
       [ 3, 12, 21],
       [ 3, 13, 20],
       [ 3, 13, 21],
       [ 4, 10, 20],
       [ 4, 10, 21],
       [ 4, 11, 20],
       [ 4, 11, 21],
       [ 4, 12, 20],
       [ 4, 12, 21],
       [ 4, 13, 20],
       [ 4, 13, 21],
       [ 5, 10, 20],
       [ 5, 10, 21],
       [ 5, 11, 20],
       [ 5, 11, 21],
       [ 5, 12, 20],
       [ 5, 12, 21],
       [ 5, 13, 20],
       [ 5, 13, 21]])
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def loopy_app():
    x1 = range(10,311)
    y1 = range(10,311)
    z1 = range(0,66)

    points1 = vtk.vtkPoints()                      
    for coords in itertools.product(x1,y1,z1):
       points1.InsertNextPoint(coords)
    return points1

def vectorized_app():
    out_data = create_mgrid_array(10,311,10,311,0,66,dtype=float)
    vtk_data_array = numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(num_array=out_data,\
                                    deep=True,array_type=vtk.VTK_FLOAT)

    points2 = vtk.vtkPoints()
    points2.SetData(vtk_data_array)
    return points2
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [155]: # Verify outputs with loopy and vectorized approaches    
     ...: out1 =  vtk_to_numpy(loopy_app().GetData())
     ...: out2 =  vtk_to_numpy(vectorized_app().GetData())
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
     ...: 
True

In [156]: %timeit loopy_app()
1 loops, best of 3: 923 ms per loop

In [157]: %timeit vectorized_app()
10 loops, best of 3: 67.3 ms per loop

In [158]: 923/67.3
Out[158]: 13.714710252600298
```

**`13x+`** speedup there with the proposed vectorized one over the loopy one!

Comment: Thank you :), but now i get the error: AssertionError: Only contiguous arrays are supported :(

Comment: @Varlor Use `out_data = np.ascontiguousarray(out_data)` and then feed to `numpy_to_vtk`?

Comment: nice,thank you very much, it works. But unfortunatetly it has no runtime improvments to itertools.product :(

Comment: @Varlor Check out the edits with a new initialization based approach and that shows `13x+` speedup.